# Mule 3.9 - Unable to fetch xml value using foreach of Xpath3 NODESET

Tags: xpath, mule, mule4, mule-esb

I am unable to retrieve the XML values using the below code snippet in Mule 3.9.5 and it works with the lower versions.  I am looking for the solutions in XPath using foreach only not splitter as per my use-case.

Mule flow XML

`<foreach collection="#[xpath3('/ParentData/Data', payload, 'NODESET')]">`

Sample XML

```
<ParentData>
  <Data>
    <test1>value1</test1>
    <test2>value2</test2>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <test1>value1</test1>
    <test2>value2</test2>
  </Data>
</ParentData>
```

Actual Output

```
[]
```

Expected Output

```
<Data>
    <test1>value1</test1>
    <test2>value2</test2>
</Data>
<Data>
    <test1>value1</test1>
    <test2>value2</test2>
</Data>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why it has to be spath explicitly? What is the reason tonot accept other potential solutions? And what is the expected output from? Xpath expression or foreach?

Comment: I think I posted all the details you have asked

Comment: I don't think so. I wouldn't have asked in that case.

Comment: You can see the expected output in the post itself and the reason being why I am looking for foreach with XPath to avoid repetitive code changes.  Is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath3() returns a list of nodes of the XML implemented with Java class `net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMNodeList`. For some reason it doesn't print the details of each node in a `<logger>`.

I think it is clearer, more intuitive, better documented and portable to future versions of Mule to use DataWeave script instead.

Example:

```
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
          <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml" />
          <dw:set-variable variableName="data"><![CDATA[
            %dw 1.0
            %output application/java
            ---
            payload.ParentData.*Data
          ]]>
          </dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>    
    
        <foreach collection="#[flowVars.data]" doc:name="For Each">
            <logger message="Data=#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </foreach>
```

Output:

```
Data={test1=value1, test2=value2}
Data={test1=value1, test2=value2}
```

In Mule 4 you can use the DataWeave expression directly in the `<foreach>`.

Comment: No doubt, this is perfect. Thanks.  Is it something with Mule expression language instead of DW?

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Above the solution with Dataweave but I am exploring with Mule expressions only with help of xpath3.